# ¿Es posible agregar ceros a la derecha de un número en SQL?

Tags: sql-server

¡Hola!
¿Es posible agregar ceros a la derecha de un número hasta completar una cantidad x de caracteres en SQL? ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

En mi caso concreto, necesito completar los números de la columna "Valor" (almacenados como varchar) hasta un máximo de 8 caracteres cuyo resultado está en la columna "Resultado esperado".

Por ejemplo:
Valor:               Resultado esperado
12345                12345000
1234567              12345670
12                   12000000

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta necesita más detalles. ¿Qué tipo de dato almacenas? ¿Qué has intentado o investigado? Tal y como está redactada tu pregunta, una respuesta válida sería un simple: **sí, es posible**. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta. Puedes leer [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esto te servirá

`select LEFT(CONCAT(12345,'00000000'),8)`

`select LEFT(CONCAT(1234567,'00000000'),8)`

`select LEFT(CONCAT(12,'00000000'),8)`

Comment: Muchas gracias! 
Me funcionó a la perfección.